# how to create dict inside one more dict, without overwriting old data

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of data from which I am creating dict inside dict, structure it is coming as expected but somewhere it is overwriting, I don't know where

```
a=['t1_h1','t2_h2']
b=['h1_d1','h1_d2','h2_d3']
c=['d1_dom1','d2_dom2','d3_dom3']
d=['dom1_a','dom1_b','dom2_a','dom2_b','dom3_a','dom3_b']
```

I tried using this code

```
for item in a:
f[item.split('_')[0]]={}
for hypercube in b:
    if item.split('_')[1] in hypercube:#h1 in b

        f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]]={}

        for dimension in c:
            if hypercube.split('_')[1] in dimension:#d1 in c 
                f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]]={}
                for domain in d:
                    if dimension.split('_')[1] in domain:#dom1 in d
                        if f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]].has_key(dimension.split('_')[1]):
                            f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]][dimension.split('_')[1]].append(domain.split('_')[1])
                        else:
                            f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]][dimension.split('_')[1]]=[domain.split('_')[1]]
```

Actually I am trying to print in this format:

```
{'t1': {'h1': {'d1': {'dom1': ['a', 'b']}, 'd2': {'dom2': ['a', 'b']}}},
     't2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a', 'b']}}}}
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
{'t2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a','b']}}}, 't1': {'h1': {'d2': {'dom2': ['a','b']}}}}
```

but after changing last thing is in 't1' 'd1' value is missing

Comment: `f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]]f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]]` really? No offense, but ... you are doing a mess with all those `split` and indexing. You can benefit of using a few classes or something, so at least the members will have a name. Or at the very least use tuples instead of strings with `_`.

Comment: Looks like you're try to build a tree data structure. Consider using a recursive solution that will simplify what's going on at each level and be able to handle any number of them -- a tree of any depth.

Comment: @-rodrigo actually i am checking a link between each list item so in order to derive a dict like that i am using this..... tuples in the sense how

Comment: @martineau ya thats what i am constructing from each list item and adding to dict....but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to nest your for loops, you want to nest the for *searches* as you process each list a, b, c and d, adding deeper and deeper levels to f. This gives your desired output:

```
f = {}
for item in a:
    ak1,ak2 = item.split('_')
    f[ak1] = {ak2:{}}
for item in b:
    bk1,bk2 = item.split('_')
    next(f[akey][bk1] 
            for akey in f 
                if bk1 in f[akey])[bk2] = {}
for item in c:
    ck1,ck2 = item.split('_')
    next(f[akey][bkey][ck1] 
            for akey in f 
                for bkey in f[akey] 
                    if ck1 in f[akey][bkey])[ck2] = []
for item in d:
    dk1,dk2 = item.split('_')
    next(f[akey][bkey][ckey][dk1] 
            for akey in f 
                for bkey in f[akey]
                    for ckey in f[akey][bkey]
                        if dk1 in f[akey][bkey][ckey]).append(dk2)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(f)
```

prints:

```
{'t1': {'h1': {'d1': {'dom1': ['a', 'b']}, 'd2': {'dom2': ['a', 'b']}}},
 't2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a', 'b']}}}}
```

Comment: @ paul McGuire whats that next function do, whats the use of it... can u explain ur code.......thanks for helping

Comment: `next` is a builtin function that finds the next matching item. The purpose in this case is that it will go through all the for-loops and find the first matching case. The alternative code doing nested for loops to find the leaf node to append/insert to will require keeping a 'found' flag, breaking when the desired leaf node is found, and testing the found flag at each higher level for loop to see if it is necessary to keep looking.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire if explain this one line means enough for me next(f[akey][bk1] 
            for akey in f 
                if bk1 in f[akey])[bk2] = {}  the statements within next can u explain.. thanks once again

Comment: Equivalent to: `for akey in f.keys(): if bk1 in f[akey]: f[akey][bk1][bk2] = {}; break`. In this particular statement, `next` doesn't do much, since once a key is found, we create the subdict, break and we're done. But in the deeper for loops, we will be 2 or 3 levels deep within loops, so break has to break out multiple levels, not just one. By using `next` instead, we in essence find just the first match, and then that's all we want. The issue here is that you are looking for a *leaf* node in the tree as it has been built so far, so you have to nest your loops as much as the tree is deep.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good case to use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def new_dict(items):
    items = [i.split('_') for i in items]
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in items:
        d[k].append(v)
    return dict(d)

def combine(x,y):
    for i in x:
        x[i] = dict((j,y[j]) for j in x[i])
    return x

a, b, c, d = [new_dict(i) for i in [a, b, c, d]]

c=combine(c,d)
b=combine(b,c)
a=combine(a,b)
print a
#Output:
{'t2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a', 'b']}}},
't1': {'h1': {'d2': {'dom2': ['a', 'b']}, 'd1': {'dom1': ['a', 'b']}}}}
```

`new_dict` returns a `dict` by splitting the input strings into keys and values. The cool bit is by using `defaultdict` we can easily append additional key values to a key, without having to do any checking, ie:

`['h1_d1','h1_d2','h2_d3']` becomes: `{'h2': ['d3'], 'h1': ['d1', 'd2']}` and not `{'h2': ['d3'], 'h1': ['d2']}`

Then we combine the dicts starting at the innermost and growing outwards. This works by iterating over the keys of an outer dictionary, and replacing each value with a dict keyed by that value, and the value being the key, values pair from the inner dict.

Comment: @ fraxel thanks for the help, but can u explain how its working

Comment: @user1182090 - just about to have lunch, will add full explaination a little later, but, first we convert each list to a `defaultdict` where  first part of every string is a key and the part after '_' is a value for its key (using defualtdict means no over writes). Then when that is done we combine the dicts starting at the innermost and growing outwards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to simplify your code? Try this:

```
def pack_to_tree(*lists):

    split_ = lambda l: (i.split('_',1) for i in l)

    # last level
    result = {}
    for k, v in split_(lists[-1]):
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    # other levels
    for d in lists[-2::-1]:
        subresult = {}
        for k, v in split_(d):
            subresult.setdefault(k, {})[v] = result[v]
        result = subresult
    return result

a = ['t1_h1', 't2_h2']
b = ['h1_d1', 'h1_d2', 'h2_d3']
c = ['d1_dom1', 'd2_dom2', 'd3_dom3']
d = ['dom1_a', 'dom1_b', 'dom2_a', 'dom2_b', 'dom3_a', 'dom3_b']

print pack_to_tree(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: @ astynax, thanks for the help but {'t2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a', 'b']}}}, 't1': {'h1': {'d2': {'dom2': ['a', 'b']}}}} it print like this... in this 'h1'-> 'd1' link is missing

Answer (score 0):

It is rather hard to read that code, but I think that in lines that you create new dictionaries (`...={}`) and especially the new linked list (`...=[]`) you should try something like:

```
if (not  f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]][dimension.split('_')[1]]):
   f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]][dimension.split('_')[1]]=[]
f[item.split('_')[0]][item.split('_')[1]][hypercube.split('_')[1]][dimension.split('_')[1]].append(domain.split('_')[1])
```

Then you are sure that you are not overwriting something that is already there.

Comment: @-malenkiy_scot actually i am trying to get link between in each list by substring method... i need to come with the dict structure like that.. can u help

Comment: @-malenkiy another way of representing last line of my code, but it shows some key error

Comment: @malenkiy_scot: I don't think you're doing the OP a favor encouraging the coding style they were using.

Comment: @martineau, you are right about the coding style, but it's 'one at a time' - everybody else already commented on it.

Answer (score 0):

The styles issues were already mentioned, so I concentrate on functionality. The simple bug in the original code is in the last line. Since for the **first** occurrence of a dictionary key sequence simply an empty list is assigned, the important value of

> domain.split('_')[1]

is lost.
So there is actually no overwrite, but the missing values were never stored. Filling the empty square brackets wih this term should fix this.

Comment: i not got if u can see i am appending this in last line... if u can show in my code means its very helpfull

Comment: @guidiot thanks i got my mistake but still one value is missing from dict.. now it prints {'t2': {'h2': {'d3': {'dom3': ['a', 'b']}}}, 't1': {'h1': {'d2': {'dom2': ['a', 'b']}}}}... but still in 'h1'-> 'd1' is missing... can u help it out